# NLog: How to add 2 different database targets and rules under one configuration?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nlog

I have been researching how to programmatically add multiple database targets. I only need 2, and I cannot seem to figure out how to get them to work.

I can only get 1 target and logger to work. For example, the 2 code blocks below work:

My configuration code (1 target):

```
    var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
    // Add another NLog Target (ChangeTracking)
    var changeTrackingDbTarget = new DatabaseTarget()
    {
        Name = "ChangeTracking",
        ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NLogConnection"].ConnectionString,
        CommandText = "INSERT INTO Common.ChangeTracking (ApplicationID, UserName, EntityName, PropertyName, PrimaryKeyValue, OldValue, NewValue, DateChanged) " +
                      "VALUES (@ApplicationID, @UserName, @EntityName, @PropertyName, @PrimaryKeyValue, @OldValue, @NewValue, @DateChanged);"
    };

    changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@ApplicationID", Layout = "${appsetting:name=AppID:default=null}" });
    changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@UserName", Layout = "${identity:authType=false:isAuthenticated=false}" });
    changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@EntityName", Layout = "${event-properties:item=ENTITYNAME}" });
    changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@PropertyName", Layout = "${event-properties:item=PROPNAME}" });
    changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@PrimaryKeyValue", Layout = "${event-properties:item=PRIMARYKEY}" });
    changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@OldValue", Layout = "${event-properties:item=OLDVALUE}" });
    changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@NewValue", Layout = "${event-properties:item=NEWVALUE}" });
    changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@DateChanged", Layout = "${date}" });

    config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Info, changeTrackingDbTarget));

    //LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget("ExceptionTracking", dbTarget);
    LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

My code that calls the logs (1 target):

```
private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("ChangeTracking");
                        LogEventInfo changeEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, "ChangeTracking", "A change event has been fired");
                        changeEvent.Properties["ENTITYNAME"] = entityName;
                        changeEvent.Properties["PROPNAME"] = prop;
                        changeEvent.Properties["PRIMARYKEY"] = primaryKey;
                        changeEvent.Properties["OLDVALUE"] = originalValueString;
                        changeEvent.Properties["NEWVALUE"] = currentValueString;
                        _logger.Log(changeEvent);
```

My configuration code (2 targets):

```
    // Setup NLOG Database Target for Exception Tracking
    LogManager.ThrowExceptions = true;
    var dbTargetExceptions = new DatabaseTarget()
    {
        Name = "ExceptionTracking",
        ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NLogConnection"].ConnectionString,
        CommandText = "INSERT INTO Common.ExceptionTracking ( ApplicationID,  Url,  IP,  Referrer,  UserName,  ExceptionDescription,  Action,  Controller,  InsertedBy,  InsertedDate) " +
                                                    "VALUES (@ApplicationID, @Url, @IP, @Referrer, @UserName, @ExceptionDescription, @Action, @Controller, @InsertedBy, @InsertedDate);"
    };
    dbTargetExceptions.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@ApplicationID", Layout = "${appsetting:name=AppID:default=null}" });
    dbTargetExceptions.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@Url", Layout = "${aspnet-Request-Url}" });
    dbTargetExceptions.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@IP", Layout = "${aspnet-Request-IP}" });
    dbTargetExceptions.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@Referrer", Layout = "${aspnet-Request-Referrer}" });
    dbTargetExceptions.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@UserName", Layout = "${identity:authType=false:isAuthenticated=false}" });
    dbTargetExceptions.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@ExceptionDescription", Layout = "${exception:tostring}" });
    dbTargetExceptions.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@Action", Layout = "${aspnet-MVC-Action}" });
    dbTargetExceptions.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@Controller", Layout = "${aspnet-MVC-Controller}" });
    dbTargetExceptions.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@InsertedBy", Layout = "${gdc:BEMSID}" });
    dbTargetExceptions.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@InsertedDate", Layout = "${date}" });

    // Setup NLOG Database Target for Change Tracking
        var changeTrackingDbTarget = new DatabaseTarget()
        {
            Name = "ChangeTracking",
            ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NLogConnection"].ConnectionString,
            CommandText = "INSERT INTO Common.ChangeTracking (ApplicationID, UserName, EntityName, PropertyName, PrimaryKeyValue, OldValue, NewValue, DateChanged) " +
                          "VALUES (@ApplicationID, @UserName, @EntityName, @PropertyName, @PrimaryKeyValue, @OldValue, @NewValue, @DateChanged);"
        };

        changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@ApplicationID", Layout = "${appsetting:name=AppID:default=null}" });
        changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@UserName", Layout = "${identity:authType=false:isAuthenticated=false}" });
        changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@EntityName", Layout = "${event-properties:item=ENTITYNAME}" });
        changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@PropertyName", Layout = "${event-properties:item=PROPNAME}" });
        changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@PrimaryKeyValue", Layout = "${event-properties:item=PRIMARYKEY}" });
        changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@OldValue", Layout = "${event-properties:item=OLDVALUE}" });
        changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@NewValue", Layout = "${event-properties:item=NEWVALUE}" });
        changeTrackingDbTarget.Parameters.Add(new DatabaseParameterInfo() { Name = "@DateChanged", Layout = "${date}" });

    //Setup NLOG Configuration. Adding DB Targets and Rules for Targets
    LoggingConfiguration nLogConfig = new LoggingConfiguration();
    nLogConfig.AddTarget("ExceptionTracking", dbTargetExceptions);
    nLogConfig.AddTarget("ChangeTracking", dbTargetChanges);
    nLogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("ChangeLogger", LogLevel.Info, dbTargetChanges));
    nLogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, dbTargetExceptions));

    //Finally set the configuration above to the LogManager config property
    LogManager.Configuration = nLogConfig;
```

My code that calls the log(2 targets):

```
 private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("ChangeTracking");
                        LogEventInfo changeEvent = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Info, "ChangeTracking", "A change event has been fired");
                        changeEvent.Properties["ENTITYNAME"] = entityName;
                        changeEvent.Properties["PROPNAME"] = prop;
                        changeEvent.Properties["PRIMARYKEY"] = primaryKey;
                        changeEvent.Properties["OLDVALUE"] = originalValueString;
                        changeEvent.Properties["NEWVALUE"] = currentValueString;
                        _logger.Log(changeEvent);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what "If I remove one from the configuration, the other works." means. Please show the code with the "removal"

Comment: PS in general one `?` is enough to make it a question ;)

Comment: A question mark for every day that I have been working on this

Comment: Really my question is simple. How do I programmatically add 2 database targets and log to them? If I remove one target's code, it works. It will not work with 2 targets.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the GDC right? Still it looks like you need event-properties.

Comment: Any reason why you are creating the `LogEventInfo` by hand, and not doing `_logger.Info("A change event has been fired")`?

Comment: I have updated my post to include the code that works, as well as the code that doesnt. I have updated it to use EventInfo instead of GDC. Also, I thought that I had to create LogEventInfo by hand, that is just the way I figured out how to do it online with custom properties.

Comment: about the properties, you could use now `WithProperty` or structured logging. It's not mandatory, but I think it's less verbose. See https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Context#logevent-properties

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207711/discussion-between-julian-and-jakefromstatefarm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config is correct. The AddTarget is not really necessary as you pass the Target to the rule and the Target has the same name property. So this should be enough:

```cs
LoggingConfiguration nLogConfig = new LoggingConfiguration();
nLogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("ChangeLogger", LogLevel.Info, dbTargetChanges));
nLogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, dbTargetExceptions));

//Finally set the configuration above to the LogManager config property
LogManager.Configuration = nLogConfig;
```

I personally prefer the `AddRule` on `LoggingConfiguration`. This is the same as above, but  `AddRule`-style:

```cs
LoggingConfiguration nLogConfig = new LoggingConfiguration();
nLogConfig.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, dbTargetChanges, "ChangeLogger");
nLogConfig.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, dbTargetExceptions);

//Finally set the configuration above to the LogManager config property
LogManager.Configuration = nLogConfig;
```

If this won't work in your change, [enable and check the internal log](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Internal-logging) on trace level.

> and the other I want to call by default everywhere else

Please note is that the rules are processed from top to bottom and will only stop if you add "final" (or a condition that won't match).

So for above config, writing to the "ChangeLogger" will write to **both** targets. I'm not sure if that is what you need. If not then:

- Or add `Final = true` to the first rule

  ```
  // Old style
  nLogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("ChangeLogger", LogLevel.Info, dbTargetChanges){Final = true});
  nLogConfig.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, dbTargetExceptions));
  // Or AddRule style:
  nLogConfig.AddRule(LogLevel.Info, LogLevel.Fatal, dbTargetChanges, "ChangeLogger", true);  
  nLogConfig.AddRule(LogLevel.Trace, LogLevel.Fatal, dbTargetExceptions);
  ```
- Or add a condition/filter to the 2nd rule.

### after update

I think your issue was here, it add the target under the name "ExceptionTracking", while the rule is made to "ChangeTracking". I think this was enabled when testing:

```
 //LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget("ExceptionTracking", dbTarget);
```

I added some comments to make things clear:

```
var changeTrackingDbTarget = new DatabaseTarget()
{
    Name = "ChangeTracking",
  ...
};

...

// add rule to target with name ChangeTracking
config.LoggingRules.Add(new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Info, changeTrackingDbTarget));

// register target not under ChangeTracking, but under ExceptionTracking
LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget("ExceptionTracking", dbTarget);
LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

Comment: This was very helpful, thank you. I didn't realize the importance of naming the LoggingRule and Target the same... in my case "ChangeTracking".